# why this program using single pointer is not working

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

If we use double pointer instead of single pointer this code is working properly..

```
Node *pairwiseSwap(Node *start)
{
    Node *prev=start,*current=start->next;
    if(start==NULL || start->next==NULL)
    return 0;
    while(true)
    {
        Node *next=current->next;
        current->next=prev;
        if(next==NULL || next->next==NULL)
        {
            prev->next=next;
            break;
        }
        prev->next=next->next;**//next to next**
        prev=next;
        current=prev->next;**//appending nodes to the previous one**
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by (not) working?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you're having? Does it build? If not then what errors do you get? Does it crash run-time? Then where do the debugger tell you it crashes? Unexpected results? What results did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: Doing this check `if(start==NULL || start->next==NULL)` *after* `Node *prev=start,*current=start->next;` doesn't work. The damage is already done, `NULL` possibly dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Node *prev=start,*current=start->next;
    if(start==NULL || start->next==NULL)
```

here's your problem.

if `start==NULL` you get an error when doing `current=start->next`, since you are trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer

I assume you are trying to do something on a linked list, and you want to return 0 (a `NULL` pointer) in case the list has just one element.

If this is the case, it's enough to swap the first two instructions of the function

Comment: That's not related to what I'm saying, as he does `current=start->next` before checking if `start==NULL`.
The `if` statement itself is right, the problem is in the order of instructions

EDIT: I realize that in my answer the reference to the access to `start->next` was a bit ambiguous, I'll edit it, ty

Answer (score 0):

you first have to correct this:

```
 Node *prev=start,*current=start->next;
                          /* ^___ start can it be null? */
                          /* according to the next code, yes it can */
if(start==NULL || start->next==NULL) /*test if start is null*/
return 0;
```

change it to thsi:

```
Node *prev,*current;
if(start==NULL || start->next==NULL)
return 0;

prev=start;
current=start->next;
```

then describe your problem clearly